# Unable to get PhpStorm to connect to Xdebug running in WSL 2

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am having trouble getting PhpStorm 2020.2 to work with xdebug with the following setup:
WSL2 running Ubuntu 20, with PHP and php-xdebug installed. Whenever I run my tests with debugging enabled it says "Connection was not established.".

This is what the Xdebug log shows:

```
[5877] Log opened at 2020-08-14 17:20:45
[5877] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.18.48.1:9006.
[5877] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
[5877] Log closed at 2020-08-14 17:20:46
```

**This is for CLI only**, I'm not trying to connect via php-fpm (so no Apache, nginx, ...).

So far I have tried:

- Changing the port to something other than 9000 (portscans also reveal that none of them are in use).
- Adding a firewall rule to allow incoming requests as described in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585#issuecomment-610061194 (as well as restarting a couple times after adding the rule)

  ```
  New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow
  ```
- Adding options like `xdebug.remote_enable=1` to the config, but this is being done by PhpStorm anyways when it runs the remote php instance (`remote_connect_back` also did not do the trick):

  ```
  [wsl://UBUNTU2004]:php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9006 -dxdebug.remote_host=172.18.48.1 /home/spaceemotion/code/xxxxxx/backend/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit [rest ommitted]
  ```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1) Please share Xdebug section from `phpinfo()` output (e.g. place it in your test.php and try to debug it). 2) Show Xdebug related settings from PhpStorm as well. 3) *"Unable to get PhpStorm to connect to Xdebug"* It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around. 4) *"remote_connect_back also did not do the trick"* That's correct -- that option does nothing in CLI as PHP simply has no `$_SERVER` filled (only for web requests). 5) The issue might be in IP address detection by PhpStorm. It has to be the IP where PhpStorm is running (as seen from inside WSL).

Comment: 6) When debug session is attempted by IDE ("phone handle" icon is green/IDE listens for incoming connections): double check that it's PhpStorm that listens on Xdebug port (`netstat` or alike) 7) Make sure that PhpStorm is allowed in firewall (may even try disabling it completely for your tests duration). 8) Try connecting from WSL to your host OS (Windows 10) using `telnet` -- if all good (host:port is correct, no issues with firewall) it will establish a connection (just as Xdebug would).

Comment: Just in case: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html & https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html Sadly I have not tried WSL debugging yet myself, so do not know about any pre-requirements that may be needed (like firewall rule that would allow making a connection from WSL to the host etc).

Comment: Ouch. the firewall trick actually helped me find the issue. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000436444/comments/360000168070 talks about a completely different dialog for firewall settings than the one(s) I've tried. Checked the boxes for phpstorm and now it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000436444/comments/360000168070

> In Windows Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall you can see a list of software that is allowed to communicate through private and public networks.

Make sure the phpstorm.exe is actually allowed (for me the private network options were unchecked).

Comment: I ran in the same problem with Visual Studio Code. The solution for me was to add an Allow rule in the advanced Firewall settings of Windows. You must also modify the Block rule, to allow the traffic you just defined in the newly created Allow rule. Block rules are given priority by Windows.
The essence of the problem is, that the WSL network interface is seen as a public network location. And for vscode, there were 4 rules. TCP/UDP block for public. TCP/UDP allow for private.