# From inside of a Docker container how to connect to a WSL2 distribution

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, wsl-2

**Setup**

- Docker host on Windows using WSL 2 engine
- Linux (Ubuntu-20.04) WSL 2 Distribution with WSL 2 integration
- Docker container (`webdevops/php-apache-dev`) started from Ubuntu
- Container port mapping 8000:8000

The PHP Web Application in the docker container is now reachable from Windows host via http://localhost:8000

Running PhpStorm on Windows and this Xdebug settings in the php-apache-dev container:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal
```

Xdebug connects to PhpStorm at port 9000, debugging is fine.

xdebug log:

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
...
```

If I run PhpStorm on Ubuntu, Xdebug is not able to reach PhpStorm.

Xdebug Log:

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
```

**How am I able to debug the php application in PhpStorm starting from my WSL2 Ubuntu?**

The reason why is performance. PhpStorm file indexing in Ubuntu is quite faster than from Windows via `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04`

Comment: If i start a sshd service on Ubuntu, a `ssh host.docker.internal` from the container opens a shell on Ubnutu as expected. But not the xdebug connection still does not work.

Comment: AFAIK `host.docker.internal` is available on Windows/Mac only and NOT on Linux: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264 (although some new Docker builds may have that already: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-714253414). So check what IP the `host.docker.internal` domain gets resolved to (check must be done from **inside the docker container** and not elsewhere). In general, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container

Comment: 2) The connection ...it may still need to pass the Windows Firewall. There should be some rule/command to seamlessly forward connections from WSL2 back to the host OS (where IDE is running). Something like https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585#issuecomment-610061194. In any case: check this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420260/783119

Comment: Whatever your solution is: if it works OK for you -- post it as an answer (which you can accept later) -- it may help other users in a similar situation.

Comment: Disabling windows firewall does not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

**My solution now is a workaround:**

- PHPStorm in Ubuntu listens to port 9099,
- xdebug in docker container uses `xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal`,
- Start a ssh tunnel from Windows to Ubuntu with port forwarding 9000.9099: `ssh  -R 9000:localhost:9099 localhost`

Comment: This solution sounds great, but how did you forward the port exactly? This command returns `ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused` regardless if it's launched from WSL2 or from Windows. Is there a config parameter to change in WSL?

Comment: I managed port forwarding with this command to run in Windows Powershell: `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9003 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=9099 connectaddress=mywslipaddress`

Comment: @Bloops, what's the purpose of this 9003 listen port? Shouldn't it be 9000?

Comment: @Raisen xdebug3 uses by default 9003. You can forward 9000 as well

Comment: This answer saved my day